# Is it possible for data from an external hard drive to be damaged due to power surge?

Tags: external-hard-drive

There was a really intense lightning storm earlier today near my house; there was a power surge/outage and my external hard drive was plugged in (but it wasn't transferring information). It seems to be working perfectly fine for now, no problems spotted; is it possible for data to have been damaged, deleted or corrupted during the power surge?

Comment: It's possible, but if that were the case you should have noticed by now. If you want to make sure you can still use the manufacturer's tool to run diagnostics and test the HDD.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but if the drive is apparently working fine, the chances that it happened are low.

And if it did happen, the chances that the corrupted data would be read with no apparent problems are very, very, very low.

In other words, you might find a file the copying of which fails with an error message relating to "unable to read", "disk error", "ecc error", that sort of thing. (And your OS error log will give more details as to the specific error.)

But it's very very very unlikely that you'd be able to read a file with corrupted data in it and have the OS just sail through it without reporting any problems.

On Windows, `chkdsk /R <drive_letter>:` , e.g. `chkdsk /R C:` (from a command prompt) will read all of the blocks, force correction of any with correctable errors, and report any noncorrectable errors.

(n.b.: Correctable read errors happen all the time, and are silently corrected in the drive before the OS ever sees the data. Strong error correction is one reason we can pack so much stuff on hard drives.)